# How do you plot a 3d blezier curve in Javascript? ( three.js, webGL)

Tags: javascript, html, three.js

I understand how to build a simple blezier curve, but how am I able to my the curve in the 3D? and is it possible to plot multiple curves to make a image such as cone ? Any guidance will be helpful. Thank you

Here is a simple curve.

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="150" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
</canvas>

<script>

var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(20, 20);
ctx.bezierCurveTo(20, 100, 200, 100, 200, 20);
ctx.stroke();

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may find some help in the [threejs.org/docs](https://threejs.org/docs), specially [here](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/extras/core/Shape) to draw a path, create its object and include it in the scene.